# How can I minimize a Delphi application from a modal form when Win+M is pressed?

Tags: forms, delphi, modal-dialog, minimize

I have a Delphi 2009 application that contains two forms: a main form and a full screen modal form. How can I make my app minimize when the modal form is open and I press Win+M?

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: I don't think you can. This is OS behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps there's something about the way you put your app together. That's why a [mcve] would help.

Comment: Related : [Proper handling of modal window "Minimize" behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303621/)

Comment: The "related" section also have a few related questions.